# How to know a promise has been fulfilled so I can chain to it or use its result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When a user selects an employee, I make an async request to the server for the employee's events.  If the user then proceeds to assign a task to the employee they selected before the server can respond with the event list for the employee, I need to defer that assignment until the event list arrives.  The event list is loaded via `$http.get()` so I have a promise to work from.  But what if that promise has already been satisfied?  The event list might look like an empty array, so I can't rely on looking at the array to know if it has been satisfied.

If I add a .then to an already satisfied promise, does it get called immediately?

Answer (score 2):

The function that you've passed to `then` will execute immediately if the promise has been resolved.